# Update props fetched from reducer in component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting new data in my reducer, and accessing state in component via props, but props is not updated when state is updated in reducer. I need to somehow check when props is updated, `componentDidMount`?

I've tried to access the state in component via `this.props.list`. In reducer, state is update when new item is added to list via a websocket

```
// Reducer
case types.ADD_LIST:
return {
  lists: action.lists
}

// Somewhere in My component
{this.props.lists ? this.props.lists.map((list, index) => (
   <li key={index}>list</li>
)}
```

Comment: How do you pass the props to your component?

Comment: via react-redux `connect` function i.e. `connect(state => ({ lists: state.lists, ... })`

Comment: Are you sure it gets updated in the redux store? So you dispatch an action for ADD_LIST, it goes through reducer and updates the store, but not affecting your component?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Yes, it only renders the first item in the list, but doesn't update when second item is added, I can see item has been added to list in reducer on inspection

Answer (score 1):

State wouldn't automatically get mapped to your component's props. You should use react-redux to map Redux state to your props. Specifically using the `connect` method in your component.

example:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    lists: state.lists
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName);
```

don't forget to wrap your app component inside a Provider and pass your store to it:

```
  <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using connect function, you have to pass state to your component.
try like this,

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    lists: state.lists
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(yourComponent);
```

Comment: I do have this, but in a different syntax `export const MyComponent = connect(state => ({ lists: state.lists }), {})(MyComponent)`

Comment: ok i coldn't see (MyComponent) in your question in a connect call